# Return multiple XML nodes and Custom parent tag using FLWOR XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, xquery-sql, flwor

I need to get the following output using a FLWOR expression.

```
<oldPlanes>
  <make>Cessna</make>
  <model>Centurian</model>
  <make>Piper</make>
  <model>Tripacer</model>
</oldPlanes>
```

using

```
CREATE TABLE XMLO1 (xDoc XML NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO XMLO1 VALUES ('
 <planes>
   <plane>
     <year>1977</year>
     <make>Cessna</make>
     <model>Skyhawk</model>
     <color>Light blue and white</color>
   </plane>
   <plane>
     <year>1975</year>
     <make>Piper</make>
     <model>Apache</model>
     <color>White</color>
   </plane>
   <plane>
     <year>1960</year>
     <make>Cessna</make>
     <model>Senturian</model>
     <color>Yellow and White</color>
   </plane>
   <plane>
     <year>1956</year>
     <make>Piper</make>
     <model>ripacer</model>
     <color>Blue</color>
   </plane>
 </planes>')
```

I tried the below query

```
SELECT xDoc.query('for $p in //plane
                    let $x:=$p/year
                    where $x < 1970
                    return <oldPlanes><make>{data($p/make)}</make> 
                           </oldPlanes>
                    ')
FROM XMLO1
```

This doesn't gives me the expected output to find the planes where `Year < 1970`.

**How to set a custom parent node as `<oldPlanes>`**

**How to return 2 nodes as the expected output?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to create one `oldPlanes` element so its construction needs to be outside the FLWOR expression:

```
<oldPlanes>{for $p in //plane
            let $x:=$p/year
            where $x < 1970
            return $p/(make, model)}</oldPlanes>
```

Except that you don't need a FLWOR for this at all, a simple path expression will do the job:

```
<oldPlanes>{//plane[year < 1970]/(make, model)}</oldPlanes>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I was able to get the required output as below.

`SELECT xDoc.query('let $planes := planes/plane
return <oldPlanes>{
 for $x in $planes
 where $x/year < 1970
 return ($x/make,$x/model)
}</oldPlanes>')
FROM XMLO1
`

Comment: Could you please help me on this as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803940/concat-xml-nodes-using-xquery