# Concat XML nodes using XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql, flwor

I required the following output

```
<name>Thomas Mapother</name>
<name>Tom Cruise</name>
```

using the below XML using XQuery FLOWR Expressions.

```
INSERT INTO XMLO1 VALUES ('<Contact>
<Names>
    <Name Type = "Legal">
        <First>Thomas</First>
        <Middle>T</Middle>
        <Last>Mapother</Last>
    </Name>
    <Name Type = "Stage">
        <First>Tom</First>
        <Middle>C</Middle>
        <Last>Cruise</Last>
    </Name>
</Names>
</Contact>')
```

I tried the below query. But it returns a different output.

```
SELECT xDoc.query('let $names := Contact/Names/Name
return <name>{
    for $x in $names
    return ($x/First,$x/Last)}
</name>')
FROM XMLO1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select xDoc.query('
for $x in Contact/Names/Name
return element Name {concat($x/First[1]," ", $x/Last[1])}
')
from XMLO1
```

Or shred and recombine (will be faster):

```
select T.X.value('(First/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')+' '+
         T.X.value('(Last/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
from XMLO1
  cross apply xDoc.nodes('Contact/Names/Name') as T(X)
for xml path('Name');
```

Answer (score 2):

From this and from [Return multiple XML nodes and Custom parent tag using FLWOR XQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802601/return-multiple-xml-nodes-and-custom-parent-tag-using-flwor-xquery/56803693) , I think you're a bit confused about how FLWOR expressions work.

In the other question, you only wanted one wrapper element (`oldPlanes`), but you made the mistake of creating the element inside the `return` clause of a FLWOR expression, which is executed once for each node selected by the `for` clause. In this question, you have made the opposite mistake: you want one `name` element for each `Name` in the input, so you need to generate it within the `return` clause.

So instead of

```
return <name>{
    for $x in $names
    return ($x/First,$x/Last)}
</name>
```

you want

```
return 
    for $x in $names
    return <name>{($x/First,$x/Last)}</name>
```

Again, it can be simplified to

```
return $names/<name>{(First,Last)}</name>
```

Many people coming to XQuery from a SQL background make the mistake of thinking that every query has to be a FLWOR expression. In fact, the vast majority of queries don't need variables and don't need FLWOR.